# Mysql query tag search with relevance

Tags: mysql, sql, search, tags, full-text-search

I need help on creating a full text search in multiple columns.

At the end the query should return 'biz_name', first match against 'business' table then
match against 'tags' table then select biz_id from 'Business_tags' table then put together all with **prioritize** results from 'Business Table'.

**In easy explanation**, when someone search for **bank**, they should able to get business name that has 'bank' in it and business that tagged with 'bank'.

Please consider the **three** tables:

**Business Table** and **Tags Table**

```
|biz_id |biz_name      |       |tag_id |tag_name|    
|----------------------|       |----------------|
|001    |Mac burger    |       |101    |cafe    |
|002    |Citi bank     |       |102    |burger  |
|003    |Lou’s Cafe    |       |103    |drink   |
|004    |Baltic pub    |       |104    |bank    |
|005    |T2 Restaurant |       |105    |loan    |
```

**Business_tags Table**

```
|biz_id |tag_id |           
|---------------|       
|001    |102    |       
|002    |105    |       
|002    |104    |       
|003    |101    |       
|003    |103    |       
|004    |103    | 
|005    |102    | 
|005    |101    |
```

I can't not use union cause I've different number of columns.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the three tables together and also do a text search on the name.

```
SELECT business.biz_name
   FROM business,business_tags,tags
   WHERE business.biz_id = business_tags.biz_id
   AND business_tags.tag_id = tags.tag_id
   AND (business.biz_name LIKE '%bank%' OR tags.tag_name = 'bank')
```

Will that do what you want?

Comment: what about priorities?